# mupdf utilities compiled on Win8 with VS2010: are the exe's executable on every Win system?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, compilation, mupdf

I compiled the mupdf command line utilities on Windows8 with Visual Studio 2010 Professional with the included VS projects. They work. If I want to move them to another system (any Windows) is it enough to move the exe's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move them as long as they are compiled in Release mode. If they are in Debug mode the target machine will need Debug VC libraries installed. Release libraries are usually present on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is: yes. Provided that you don't move a 64bit-exe to a 32bit Windows. And provided you move any *.dll files which were compiled alongside the *.exe with them. -- Why don't you just try it?